# Find the N happy number in Scala

Tags: scala, function, functional-programming

Hi everyone I have been working on this problem which is to find the n-th happy number. But I am struggling to make it work here as it is showing

**Found:    Unit**

**Required: Int**

**Maybe you are missing an else part for the conditional?**

Here is how it works:

nThHappy(1) returns 1

• nThHappy(3) returns 10

• nThHappy(11) returns 49

• nThHappy(19) returns 97

```
def nThHappy(k: Int): Int = {
   def isHappy(n: Int): Boolean = {
     def sumOfDigitsSquared(n: Int): Int = n.toString.foldLeft(0) { (product, num) => product + num.asDigit * num.asDigit }

     def loop(seen: Set[Int], x: Int): Boolean = {
       x match {
         case 1 => true
         case _ if seen.contains(x) => false
         case _ => loop(seen + x, sumOfDigitsSquared(x))
       }
     }
     loop(Set(),n)
   }
   def helper(countN: Int,countK: Int, hNum:Int): Int =
     countK match {
     case hNum => countN
     case _ => {
       if (isHappy(countN) == false) {
         helper(countN+1, countK, hNum)
       }
     else if(isHappy(countN) == true) { // <-- Here is the problem
         helper(countN+1, countK+1, hNum)
       }

     }
   }
   helper(0,0,k)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an `else` part for that last `if`, or just remove the test (which is pointless), or just use `match`:

```
 case _ if isHappy(countN) =>
     helper(countN+1, countK+1, hNum)
 case _ =>
     helper(countN+1, countK, hNum)
```